# Pandas Tkinter Excel Data Cleaner GUI - Need a Guru to give a novice some tips on improvements

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

My first Major Stack overflow post,

Hello I'm Warwick,

I built a GUI tool that takes excel files and outputs a finished report to help automate a report at work. It was a fantastic learning experienced and I feel much more comfortable with pandas and python, but I am very aware of some bad programming practices I have included.

I am self taught, and a little stuck on what I should focus on how to improve my programe, I'm just looking to be pointed in the right direction.

Most of the program is wrapped into one "Try/Except" block. I'm really not experienced enough to know what else I can do to improve it, aside from implementing some DRY and wrapping part of the program into a function so its not repeated for multiple files.

Could a pandas guru or python guru give me a nudge in the right direction? I'm hitting a block on best practices to implement.

Thanks guys

```
import Tkinter
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter


class simpleapp_tk(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
    self.initialize()

def initialize(self):
    self.grid() # Create the grid


    #Label for entering filename
    label_one = Tkinter.Label(self, text="Please Enter a Filename:",anchor="w",fg="black",
                              font="Times_New_Roman 10 bold")                              
    label_one.grid(column=0,row=1,sticky='W')


    #Label for entering filename
    label_one2 = Tkinter.Label(self, text="Please Enter a 2nd Filename:",anchor="w",fg="black",
                              font="Times_New_Roman 10 bold")                              
    label_one2.grid(column=0,row=2,sticky='W')      


    #Example label
    label_two = Tkinter.Label(self, text="RXInfoAug1.xlsx",anchor="center",fg="black",
                              font="Times_New_Roman 10")

    label_two.grid(column=1,row=3,sticky='EW')


    #Creating label area for user information.
    label_three = Tkinter.Label(self, text="Please select User:",anchor='w',fg='black',
                                font="Times_New_Roman 10 bold")
    label_three.grid(column=0,row=4,sticky='EW')



    #Label four is for EXAMPLE text
    label_four = Tkinter.Label(self,text="Example:",anchor='w',fg='black',
                               font="Times_New_Roman 10 bold")
    label_four.grid(column=0,row=3,sticky='W')


    #Label five is below Generate RX report, spits out result information.
    label_five = Tkinter.Label(self,text="----------Result Info----------",anchor='center',
                               fg='black',font="Times_New_Roman 10 bold")
    label_five.grid(column=0,row=6,sticky='EW',columnspan=2)


    #Label six is return information after clicking the button
    self.labelVariable_six = Tkinter.StringVar()  #have to create a variable to return

    label_six = Tkinter.Label(self,text="None",anchor='center',fg='white',bg="blue",
                              font='Times_New_Roman 10 bold',
                              textvariable=self.labelVariable_six) #notice the return variable
    label_six.grid(column=0,row=8,sticky='EW',columnspan=2)

    #Label seven is more return information, pertaining to after you click the button.
    self.labelVariable_seven = Tkinter.StringVar() #creating the return variable

    label_seven = Tkinter.Label(self,text="None",anchor='center',fg='white',bg='blue',
                                font='Times_New_Roman 10 bold',
                                textvariable=self.labelVariable_seven)
    label_seven.grid(column=0,row=9,sticky='EW',columnspan=2)


    #Entry Variable creation and location set.
    self.entryVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()
    self.entry = Tkinter.Entry(self,textvariable=self.entryVariable) #NOTICE the entry var name
    self.entry.grid(column=1,row=1,sticky='EW')

    #Entry Variable2 creation and location set.
    self.entryVariable2 = Tkinter.StringVar()
    self.entry2 = Tkinter.Entry(self,textvariable=self.entryVariable2) #NOTICE the entry var name
    self.entry2.grid(column=1,row=2,sticky='EW')        


    #Creating the variable of which user used by option menu
    self.var = Tkinter.StringVar(self)
    self.var.set("User")

    #Creating a drop down menu for user selection
    self.option_menu = Tkinter.OptionMenu(self, self.var, "Corey","Warwick","Jane", "Jacque")
    self.option_menu.grid(column=1,row=4,sticky='EW')


    #Button to generate reports - When clicked runs OnButtonClick
    button = Tkinter.Button(self,text="Generate RX Report",
                            font="Times_New_Roman 12 bold",
                            command=self.OnButtonClick)
    button.grid(column=0,row=6,sticky="EW",columnspan=2)




    #Layout management area
    self.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
    self.grid_columnconfigure(1,weight=1)

    #Layout Manager resizes if you adjust window
    self.resizable(True,True)
    self.update()
    #sets canvas size (Length, depth)
    self.geometry("320x170+300+300")
    self.entry.focus_set()
    self.entry.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)
    self.entry2.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)


def OnButtonClick(self):
    UserName = self.var.get()
    FileName = self.entryVariable.get()  

    if len(self.entryVariable2.get()) > 0:
        FileName2 = self.entryVariable2.get()
    else:
        FileName2 = self.entryVariable.get()






    if UserName == "User":
        self.labelVariable_six.set("Please select a User before Continuing")
        self.labelVariable_seven.set("")                
    elif UserName == "Corey":
        FilePath = "\cashley\Desktop\\"
        self.labelVariable_six.set("Welcome Corey, enjoy the report.")
        self.labelVariable_seven.set("Output file is located on desktop")
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter('C:\\Users\\cashley\\Desktop\\RX_STATS.xlsx')
    elif UserName == "Warwick":
        FilePath = "\wbarlow.GMSPRIMARY\Desktop\\"
        self.labelVariable_six.set("Welcome Warwick, always great to see you")
        self.labelVariable_seven.set("Output file is RX_STATS located on desktop")
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter('C:\\Users\\wbarlow.GMSPRIMARY\\Desktop\\RX_STATS.xlsx')
    elif UserName == "Jane":
        FilePath = "\janen.GMSPRIMARY\Desktop\\"
        self.labelVariable_six.set("Welcome Jane, enjoy the report")
        self.labelVariable_seven.set("Output file is RX_STATS located on desktop")
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter('C:\\Users\\janen.GMSPRIMARY\\Desktop\\RX_STATS.xlsx')
    elif UserName == "Jacque":
        FilePath = "\jacquea\Desktop\\"
        self.labelVariable_six.set("Welcome Jacquea, enjoy the report")
        self.labelVariable_seven.set("Output file is RX_STATS located on desktop")
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter('C:\\Users\\jacquea\\Desktop\\RX_STATS.xlsx')

    try:

        df = pd.read_excel("C:\Users" + FilePath + FileName)

        #DF_C Was added in so you can bring two files in to compare the two.
        df_C = pd.read_excel("C:\Users" + FilePath + FileName2)

        df.columns = ['GROUP','MEMBER_NAME','DRUG','CLAIM_DATE','SUB_QUANT','DAYS_SUPPLY','COPAY_AMT','TOTAL_COST']
        df_C.columns = ['GROUP','MEMBER_NAME','DRUG','CLAIM_DATE','SUB_QUANT','DAYS_SUPPLY','COPAY_AMT','TOTAL_COST']

        df['GROUP'] = df['GROUP'].astype(str)
        df_C['GROUP'] = df_C['GROUP'].astype(str)

        total_expense = df['TOTAL_COST'].sum()
        Y = total_expense * .80
        df['PERCENT'] = (df['TOTAL_COST'] / total_expense).round(4)

        #Bad DRY here but metrics for analysis for df_C
        total_expense_C = df_C['TOTAL_COST'].sum()
        Y_C = total_expense_C * .80
        df_C['PERCENT'] = (df_C['TOTAL_COST'] / total_expense_C).round(4)            




        emp_dict = {



        }


        df['MEMBER_NAME'].replace(emp_dict, inplace=True)
        df.loc[df.DRUG.isin(['LATUDA TAB 20MG', 'LATUDA TAB 60MG','LATUDA TAB 40MG']), 'DRUG'] = 'LATUDA TAB'
        df.loc[df.DRUG.isin(['HUMIRA START KIT 40MG PEN', 'HUMIRA PEN INJ 40MG/0.8','HUMIRA KIT 40MG SYN']), 'DRUG'] = 'HUMIRA'
        df.loc[df.DRUG.isin(['ENBREL SCLIK SYR 50MG/ML', 'ENBREL SYR 50MG/ML','ENBREL SYR 25/0.5ML']), 'DRUG'] = 'ENBREL'
        df.loc[df.DRUG.isin(['TRULICITY(4) PEN 1.5/0.5', 'TRULICITY(4) PEN 0.75/0.5']), 'DRUG'] = 'TRULICITY'


        df_C['MEMBER_NAME'].replace(emp_dict, inplace=True)
        df_C.loc[df_C.DRUG.isin(['LATUDA TAB 20MG', 'LATUDA TAB 60MG','LATUDA TAB 40MG']), 'DRUG'] = 'LATUDA TAB'
        df_C.loc[df_C.DRUG.isin(['HUMIRA START KIT 40MG PEN', 'HUMIRA PEN INJ 40MG/0.8','HUMIRA KIT 40MG SYN']), 'DRUG'] = 'HUMIRA'
        df_C.loc[df_C.DRUG.isin(['ENBREL SCLIK SYR 50MG/ML', 'ENBREL SYR 50MG/ML','ENBREL SYR 25/0.5ML']), 'DRUG'] = 'ENBREL'
        df_C.loc[df_C.DRUG.isin(['TRULICITY(4) PEN 1.5/0.5', 'TRULICITY(4) PEN 0.75/0.5']), 'DRUG'] = 'TRULICITY'            




        df2 = df['TOTAL_COST'].groupby(df['MEMBER_NAME']).sum().nlargest(10)
        df3 = df['TOTAL_COST'].groupby(df['DRUG']).sum().nlargest(20)
        df4 = df['MEMBER_NAME'].value_counts().nlargest(20)
        df5 = df['PERCENT'].groupby(df['MEMBER_NAME']).sum().nlargest(20)
        df7 = df[df['TOTAL_COST'] > 0]
        df8 = df['TOTAL_COST'].groupby(df['MEMBER_NAME']).sum().nlargest(1000)
        df13 = df['TOTAL_COST'].groupby(df['GROUP']).sum().nlargest(5)

        count = 0
        total = 0
        for row in df8:
            if total < Y:
                total = total + row
                count += 1
        WW = count

        #Count of how many Members are in the file. It combines duplicate individuals with nunique.
        Ind_count = df['MEMBER_NAME'].nunique()
        # Count of non zero individuals in the file.
        Ind_count_nonzero = df7['MEMBER_NAME'].nunique()

        # Finding what 20 percent of the total is
        twenty_percent1 = Ind_count_nonzero * .20
        twenty_percent = round(twenty_percent1,0)

        row_count = df.shape[0]

        df10 = df['PERCENT'].groupby(df['MEMBER_NAME']).sum().nlargest(WW)

        group_dict = {

        }





        df['GROUP'].replace(group_dict, inplace=True)

        df_C['GROUP'].replace(group_dict, inplace=True)

        df15 = df_C[~df_C.MEMBER_NAME.isin(df.MEMBER_NAME)] 
        pivot_C = pd.pivot_table(df15, index=['MEMBER_NAME','GROUP'],values=['TOTAL_COST'], aggfunc='sum')           
        pivot_C2 = pivot_C.sort_values(by=['TOTAL_COST'],ascending=False)
        pv_C = pivot_C2.head(20)
        pv_C2 = pv_C.reset_index()



        df13 = df['TOTAL_COST'].groupby(df['GROUP']).sum().nlargest(5)
        df3 = df3.reset_index()
        df2 = df2.reset_index()
        df4 = df4.reset_index()
        df5 = df5.reset_index()
        df10 = df10.reset_index()
        df13 = df13.reset_index()

        pivot2 = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['MEMBER_NAME','GROUP'],values=['TOTAL_COST'], aggfunc='sum')
        pivot3 = pivot2.sort_values(by=['TOTAL_COST'],ascending=False)


        pv3 = pivot3.head(20)


        pv4 = pv3.reset_index()



        writer = pd.ExcelWriter('C:\\Users' + FilePath + 'RX_STATS.xlsx')
        #writer = pd.ExcelWriter('C:\\Users\\wbarlow.GMSPRIMARY\\Desktop\\RX_STATS.xlsx')
        pv4.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Summary',index=False,header=True,startcol=0,startrow=10)
        pv_C2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Summary',index=False,header=True,startcol=0,startrow=35)
        df3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Summary',index=False,header=True,startcol=4,startrow=10)
        df4.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Summary',index=False,header=True,startcol=7,startrow=10)
        df10.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Summary',index=False,header=True,startcol=10,startrow=10)
        df13.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Summary',index=False,header=True,startcol=4,startrow=0)
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Raw Data',index=False,header=True)
        df_C.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Compare Data',index=False,header=True)

        worksheet1 = writer.sheets['Summary']
        worksheet2 = writer.sheets['Raw Data']
        worksheet3 = writer.sheets['Compare Data']
        workbook = writer.book

        format1 = workbook.add_format({'num_format':'$#,###.##'})
        format6 = workbook.add_format({'num_format':'$#,###.##','bold':True})
        format2 = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
        format5 = workbook.add_format({'bold': True,'border':1,'align':'center'})
        format3 = workbook.add_format({'bold': True, 'align': 'center'})
        format4 = workbook.add_format({'num_format':'0.00%'})
        merge_format = workbook.add_format({
            'bold':1,
            'border':1,
            'align':'center'})


        worksheet1.write('A1', "Caremark File Statistics", format2)
        worksheet1.write('A6', "Individual Count:", format2)
        worksheet1.write('A3', "Individual Non-Zero Count:", format2)
        worksheet1.write('A4', "Twenty percent of all individuals:", format2)
        worksheet1.write('A5', "Count representing eighty percent:", format2)
        worksheet1.write('A2', "RX Total Expense:", format2)

        worksheet1.write('B6', Ind_count, format2)
        worksheet1.write('B3', Ind_count_nonzero, format2)
        worksheet1.write('B4', twenty_percent, format2)
        worksheet1.write('B5', WW, format2)
        worksheet1.write('B2', total_expense, format6)


        worksheet1.conditional_format('C12:C31',{'type':'cell',
                                    'criteria':'>=',
                                    'value':1,
                                    'format':format1})

        worksheet1.conditional_format('F12:F31',{'type':'cell',
                                    'criteria':'>=',
                                    'value':1,
                                    'format':format1})

        worksheet1.conditional_format(11,11,11+WW,11,{'type':'cell',
                                    'criteria':'>=',
                                    'value':0,
                                    'format':format4})

        worksheet1.conditional_format('F2:F6',{'type':'cell',
                                    'criteria':'>=',
                                    'value':0,
                                    'format':format1})
        worksheet2.conditional_format(1,8,row_count,8,{'type':'cell',
                                    'criteria':'>=',
                                    'value':0,
                                    'format':format4})

        worksheet3.conditional_format(1,8,row_count,8,{'type':'cell',
                                    'criteria':'>=',
                                    'value':0,
                                    'format':format4})


        worksheet1.conditional_format('C37:C56',{'type':'cell',
                                    'criteria':'>=',
                                    'value':1,
                                    'format':format1})            





        worksheet1.set_column(0,0,32)
        worksheet1.set_column(1,1,35)
        worksheet1.set_column(2,2,12)
        worksheet1.set_column(3,3,5)
        worksheet1.set_column(4,4,36)
        worksheet1.set_column(5,5,12)
        worksheet1.set_column(6,6,5)
        worksheet1.set_column(7,7,30)
        worksheet1.set_column(8,8,12)
        worksheet1.set_column(9,9,5)
        worksheet1.set_column(10,10,30)
        worksheet1.set_column(11,11,12)

        worksheet2.set_column(0,0,35)
        worksheet2.set_column(1,1,30)
        worksheet2.set_column(2,2,35)
        worksheet2.set_column(3,3,20)
        worksheet2.set_column(4,4,13)
        worksheet2.set_column(5,5,13)
        worksheet2.set_column(6,6,13)
        worksheet2.set_column(7,7,13)
        worksheet2.set_column(8,8,9)


        worksheet3.set_column(0,0,35)
        worksheet3.set_column(1,1,30)
        worksheet3.set_column(2,2,35)
        worksheet3.set_column(3,3,20)
        worksheet3.set_column(4,4,13)
        worksheet3.set_column(5,5,13)
        worksheet3.set_column(6,6,13)
        worksheet3.set_column(7,7,13)
        worksheet3.set_column(8,8,9)            



        worksheet1.merge_range('A9:C9','Top Twenty Expense Individuals',merge_format)
        worksheet1.merge_range('E9:F9','Top Twenty RX Prescriptions', merge_format)
        worksheet1.merge_range('H9:I9','Top Twenty Prescription Fills Per Person', merge_format)
        worksheet1.merge_range('K9:L9','Individuals Representing 80% of Total Cost', merge_format)
        worksheet1.merge_range('A34:C34','New Individuals with Largest RX Totals', merge_format)

        worksheet1.write('H11', 'MEMBER_NAME', format5)
        worksheet1.write('I11','COUNT',format5)
        worksheet1.write('E1','LARGEST RX GROUPS',format5)
        worksheet1.write('A36','MEMBER NAME', format5)




        writer.save()
        self.entry.focus_set()
        self.entry.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)


    except:
        self.labelVariable_six.set("Confirm User is accurate.")
        self.labelVariable_seven.set("Confirm your filename.")




if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = simpleapp_tk(None)
    app.title('WB Caremark Cleaner')
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: You may be looking for the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site instead.

Comment: Some of my programming may look a little strange, I didn't know how to handle a 2nd file not existing. So it just uses the first file as the 2nd file in that instance. Obviously that isnt the best solution, but I didn't really know what to do.

Comment: Hi Warwick, I'm afraid your current question is too broad for Stack Overflow. You don't seem to have a specific programming problem, but to be looking for feedback on your already working code. Although Stack Overflow is not the right site for these kind of questions, you might be able to get the help you seek at another site on the Stack Exchange network, [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Good luck!

Comment: Yeah past posting this question, i saw their "Code Review" Section, sorry for the broad question guys! I didn't know about that code review area.